# drop down menu in fullscreen theme

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, themes, fullscreen

I am using a fullscreen theme in my app. By using this the drop-down menu button goes away, thus not letting people access the menu. How do I access the dropdown menu when in a fullscreen no action bar theme.

Comment: try to add a button on top right of application screen, and on click of it, show context menu

Comment: I tried but nothing happends